# Adjust margin: Chapter title extends in left margin

Tags: margins, chapters, document-classes, geometry

I am using a custom document class and template for my thesis. Both can be found here (they are really long, otherwise I'd copy and paste): https://wiki.cites.illinois.edu/wiki/display/ECEThesisReview/LaTeX+Resources

Here's my problem:
I set my margins using

```
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=1in,bmargin=1in,lmargin=1in,rmargin=1in}
```

Whenever I declare the option

```
\documentclass[12pt,tocnosub,fancy,offcenter]{uiucecethesis09}
```

in the preamble, the chapter number violates the my College dissertation rules that no content may extend into the one-inch margins. [image: fancy document class]

How do I modify the class file so that the chapter numbers are within the one-inch margin, i.e. move the chapter number and title over by about an inch so that it aligns to the one-inch margin?

Comment: The direct download link to the class file is here: [https://wiki.cites.illinois.edu/wiki/download/attachments/426213401/uiucecethesis09.cls?version=1&modificationDate=1285174647000&api=v2]
And the direct download link to the starter file (template) is here: [https://wiki.cites.illinois.edu/wiki/download/attachments/426213401/ecethesis.tex?version=1&modificationDate=1316699064000&api=v2]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Class files shouldn't be modified in a direct manner, only as the last-rescue way.  Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 3):

The 'offending' code is a `\llap` in the `\@makechapterhead` macro, within the `\if@thesisfancy` branch, causing the left indentation into the margin. This can be removed by applying a patch at the relevant place.

**Edit** This does not work if the chapter title is longer than the textwidth (minus the width of the chapter number figure) (so far)

```
\documentclass[12pt,tocnosub,fancy,offcenter]{uiucecethesis09}

\usepackage{geometry}

\geometry{verbose,tmargin=1in,bmargin=1in,lmargin=1in,rmargin=1in}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\leavevmode\llap}{\leavevmode}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{First}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: even if it's a bad idea, can you think in the case where chapter title is so long.

Comment: @touhami: I see what you mean. I'll try to figure out

Comment: my be a minipage in the definition of `\capchaptitle` does the job.

Comment: @touhami: I thought of a parbox, so it's similar. I have no time to figure it out right now, I am actually in a meeting ;-) Feel free to go ahead

Comment: add this if you can `\xpatchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\chaptertitlefont \capchaptitle}{\parbox{.85\textwidth}{\chaptertitlefont \capchaptitle}}{}{}` I don't want to mangling your answer

Comment: @touhami: Perhaps not mangling, but provide another one? Come on ;-)

Answer (score 3):

This is just an add to christian Hupfer's answer, in case, there is long title of chapter  (but i think it is bad idea: long text in uppercase)

```
\documentclass[12pt,tocnosub,fancy,offcenter]{uiucecethesis09}

\usepackage{geometry}

\geometry{verbose,tmargin=1in,bmargin=1in,lmargin=1in,rmargin=1in}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\leavevmode\llap}{\leavevmode}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\chaptertitlefont \capchaptitle}{\parbox{.85\textwidth}{\chaptertitlefont \capchaptitle}}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{First}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]